# Jquery Sizzle.js error for href="/link.html"

Tags: jquery, html, sizzle

I am usnig jquery version  1.9.1 for a asp.net project after completed all of the UI design, I started to assign path for the navigations as below

`<a href="../Default.aspx">Home</a>`.

But jquery sizzle throws an error:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ../Default.aspx`

Note : If I am remove the `../` means it's working properly.

How to fix this issue?

Thankyou.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your markup. The error is in your JavaScript. But since you haven't shown that to us, there's no way we can help.

Comment: `.` is a special character in jQuery selectors, if you are attempting to use it in a jquery selector, you must either wrap that section in quotes (assuming you're using an attribute selector) or escape it with two `\\`